# How can I change the timezone of the outputted date in Laravel 4?

Tags: laravel-4, timezone, php-carbon

I have a database with an `entity` table and a `users` table. The entity table has fields for `created_at` and `updated_at`. The users table has a `timezone` field with a default value of `America/Toronto`.

In my view, I can output the date in the format I want with the following code:

```
$entity->created_at->format('M j, Y \\a\\t g:i A')
```

Now, how can I output the date using the timezone field in the users table?
Something like ...

```
$entity->created_at->format('M j, Y \\a\\t g:i A', Auth::user()->timezone);
```

I am looking for a simple way to do this with [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) (since I am using Eloquent in Laravel, which will convert the above date columns to instances of Carbon).

**Note:** I only want the timezone to be changed when presenting the date - I still want all dates to be stored in the default UTC timezone in the database.

Also, where can I find a valid list of time zones that can be used with Carbon? I would like to store these in my database so users can change their default time zone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the Carbon function `copy()` to keep the timezone unchanged on your object. Then you can just set the timezone to whatever you want and 'output' the result.

```
$entity->created_at->copy()->tz(Auth::user()->timezone)->format('M j, Y \\a\\t g:i A');
```

As for timezones - [it is just PHP timezones](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php).

```
$tzlist = DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::ALL);
```

Comment: hi, im using laravel 5.1 and when I tried your solution it doesn't work. It still show the original datetime :(.