# Proper way to search event based on user date (event time stored in GMT)

Tags: php, laravel, timezone

I save event datetime in db in GMT. How can I show today's events to user?

This particularly is creating issue when date is changed due to timezone conversion.

Example:

1. User creates an event for 12 Aug 2015 23:45  (this is in his own timezone)
2. When I save it in db date becomes 13 Aug 2015 (GMT)

Now If I need to show to user all events on 12 Aug. How do I do that? What my queries will be like..

Answer (score 0):

You can use Carbon's **copy()** function for this.

See the similar question from this thread:
[How can I change the timezone of the outputted date in Laravel 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23833778/how-can-i-change-the-timezone-of-the-outputted-date-in-laravel-4)

Comment: It's not really about displaying to user. It's more about how I fetch events from a date which user gives in his own timezone. but in db it's saved in UTC